# Django: Filtering foo_set via a custom property?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model called Product with a custom property:

```
def _get_active(self):
    o = get_option()
    if self.date_expiration == None:
        return True
    if self.date_expiration <= o.working_month:
        return False
    return True
active = property(_get_active)
```

... and in one of my methods, I have this line:

```
products = g.product_set.filter(active__exact=True)
```

But despite the fact that (I think) I've correctly set up the property, the above line gives me "Cannot resolve keyword 'active' into field."  What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only query on actual fields, not properties.

Comment: `for product in (x for x in g.product_set.iterator() if x.active):`

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Ignacio's answer, you could just do:

```
products = [x for x in g.product_set.iterator() if x.active]
```

Though that's going to be very inefficient, since you've got to load every record in `x.product_set`.